# How to invert an Elliptic function where the elliptic nome is a function of an independent variable?

Tags: plotting, special-functions, expression-manipulation, inverse

I have a Jacobian elliptic function as a function of two independent variables $x$ and $y$. The elliptic parameter $m=m(y)$, $0 \leq m \leq 1$, is also a function of the variable $y$, and thus the elliptic nome $q=q(m)=q(m(y))$ also depends on $y$.

For example, I define:

$$h(y) = \ln \left(\frac{5+\sin y}{2- \cos y}\right)$$

and take $q$ such that $q = -\frac{\pi^{2}}{h(y)}$. My elliptic function is

$$f(x,y)=sn\left(\frac{2K(m)x}{h(y)},m\right),$$

where $sn$ is the Jacobian elliptic function and $K(m)=K(m(y))$ is the complete elliptic integral of the first kind, and $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

What I want is to rewrite $f(x,y)$ in terms of $x$ and $m$, instead of $y$, (and suitably normalise it) so that I could then make a contour plot of $f(x,m)$ for some level set of $f$. The problem is that I don't know how to get $Mathematica$ to invert the elliptic nome so that $y$ is expressed in terms of $m$.

My code is:

```
h[y_] := Log[(5 + Sin[y])/(2 - Cos[y])]

f[x_, y_] := (JacobiSN[2*EllipticK[InverseEllipticNomeQ[Exp[-(Pi)^2/h[y]]]]*x/h[y], InverseEllipticNomeQ[Exp[-(Pi)^2/h[y]]]])

ContourPlot[f[x, y] == 0, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

But this is not what I need.

Edit. A bit more info:

When I run the code I wrote above, the contour plot gives me a whole $\textit{set}$ of level curves of $f$, because as it stands, for any fixed $y$, the period of $f$ depends on $y$ (since the period of elliptic functions is expressed through $K(m)$, and $y$ runs through the interval $[0, 2\pi]$.

**Fixing $y = y^{*}$  for a few random values $y^{*}$  reveals that the the graph of $f(x, y^{*})$ has just one root in its appropriate period determined by $h(y)$.**

What I want is to show that this is true for all set of values  $0 \leq y \leq 2\pi$, from looking at the contour plot. As it stands, this is not clear. However, my expectation is that if I normalise $f$ properly, and use $m$ instead of $y$,  as the independent variable with $ 0\leq m \leq 1$, the contour plot should give me just one level curve, which proves the above.

Comment: If I solve the equation $w=h(y)$ for $y$, I get a complicated expression with a choice of branches for the square root and the arctangent in the result. You might want to think about which branch is most appropriate for what you want to do.

Comment: The $h(y)$ above is just a hypothetical example, my real $h$ is even more complicated. What I want is $0 \leq y \leq 2\pi$. So you suggest that I start by resolving the expression for $y$ first (say using the Inverse Function commmand)? @J.M.

Comment: "my real $h$ is even more complicated" tells me that you'll have to resort to a numerical method (i.e. `FindRoot[]`) in the worst case; as you know, most transcendental equations do not lend themselves to simple solutions. But wait, if $h(y)=-\frac{\pi^2}{q(m)}$, why not make that replacement everywhere you can?

Comment: Is this of some help [Jacobi Elliptic Functions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiEllipticFunctions.html)

Comment: That's what I tried to do (use $h(y) = \frac{\pi^{2}}{q(m)}$) but the problem is that $q(m)$ also depends on $y$? How do I define in Mathematica $y$ as a function of parameter $m$? That's where the main difficulty is @J.M.

Comment: Then it is not clear to me what you actually have, since `EllipticNomeQ[]` definitely takes the parameter $m$ as an argument. (As an aside, please mind your elliptic function notation. See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/108659).)

Comment: Please see my edited question. I hope it's a bit more clear @J.M.

Comment: Another thought: I guess this essentially amounts to ensuring that "InverseEllipticNomeQ[Exp[-(Pi)^2/h[y]]]" is always in the interval [0,1], right? @J.M.

Comment: Assuming the argument of `InverseEllipticNomeQ[]` is within $[0,1)$, the resulting $m$ should also be within $[0,1)$.

Comment: I still don't see the problem with `f[x_, m_] := JacobiSN[2*EllipticK[m]*x/(-Pi^2/Log[EllipticNomeQ[m]]),m]`